# Animation stops when cell disappear and not resume when appear again

Tags: swift, uitableview, animation, uiview, uikit

I am having simple animation (actually two of them, but will show only one for simplicity of an example) which continuously fades in, and fades out a label. So, when I scroll the tableview in such a way that some animated cells disappear, and then scroll back, those cells aren't animated anymore.

Here is the animation:

```
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(
                0.5,
                delay: 0.0,
                options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse, .AllowUserInteraction],
                animations: {
                    self.stateLabel.alpha = 0.5
             }, completion: nil)
```

I start this animation in method called setup() which is an instance method of my custom cell class (which inherits from `UITableViewCell`). As I said, there is another animation which behaves the same, and it shakes the imageview, so I am positive that this is not related to fading kind of an animation.

I invoke `setup()` method in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method after dequeuing.

What I have tried is to run this `setup()` method in `willDisplayCell` method, but the result is the same (I am not dequeueing cell in this method of course).

Also I tried with break points, and the animation code is executed. Just, animation doesn't start when cell re-appears. So the question is, how to restart / continue with animation when cell appears again?

Comment: Be sure to reset the alpha value before running this animation. You can do it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. My guess is once the you display a cell and scroll back to it the value remains the same thus no animation occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the problem is not resetting the alpha value of the UI element after displaying it. Because `UITableView` would restore but not recreate the cell if `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` function is being used. Thus resetting the alpha value on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and animating the view in `willDisplayCell` would solve the problem you were facing.